# ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Array(::Type{Int8}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64)

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

I am using Julia v0.7.0 to upgrade a package written for Julia v0.5.0. I am stuck at the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Array(::Type{Int8}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  Array(!Matched::LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling, ::Integer, ::Integer) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/LinearAlgebra/src/uniformscaling.jl:329
  Array(::Any) where T<:AbstractArray at abstractarray.jl:22
Stacktrace:
 [1] CellularAutomata.CA2d(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,2}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64) at /home/jafar_isbarov/.julia/dev/CellularAutomata/src/2dim.jl:22
 [2] CellularAutomata.CA2d(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,2}, ::Int64) at /home/jafar_isbarov/.julia/dev/CellularAutomata/src/2dim.jl:21
 [3] turbine_test() at /home/jafar_isbarov/Documents/projects/CellularAutomata.jl/test/conway_test.jl:57
 [4] top-level scope at none:0
 [5] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [6] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [7] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [8] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:239
 [9] _start() at ./client.jl:432
in expression starting at /home/jafar_isbarov/Documents/projects/CellularAutomata.jl/test/runtests.jl:3
```

Here is the line that causes it:

```
cells = Array{Int8}(h, w, gen)
```

And here is the entire block:

```
mutable struct CA2d

    #User given values
    k::Int #Number of states
    r::Int #r-nearest neigbors

    #Internal values
    cells::Array{Int8, 3}

    function CA2d(B::Array{Int,1},
                  S::Array{Int,1},
                  init::Array{Int,2},
                  gen::Int,
                  k::Int=2,
                  r::Int=1)

        h, w = size(init)
        cells = Array{Int8}(h, w, gen) #Syntax A(T, dims) is deprecated
        cells[:, :, 1] = Array{Int8}(init[:, :])

        for g = 2:gen
            for i = 1:h, j = 1:w
                cc = -cells[i, j, g-1]
                for p = (i-r):(i+r), q = (j-r):(j+r)

                    #Cyclic boundary conditions
                    if p < 1; p = h-p; end
                    if p > h; p = p-h; end
                    if q < 1; q = w-q; end
                    if q > w; q = q-w; end

                    cc += cells[p, q, g-1]
                end
                cells[i, j, g] = eval_rule(cc, cells[i, j, g-1], B, S)
            end #hw ij
        end #gen

        new(k, r, cells)
    end
end
```

I have checked and know that `h`, `w`, and `gen` are indeed integers.

You can find the entire repository [here](https://github.com/ceferisbarov/CellularAutomata.jl).

**Edit:**
When I replaced `cells = Array{Int8}(h, w, gen)` with `cells = Array{Int8}(undef, h, w, gen)`, I got the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Array(::Type{Int8}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  Array(!Matched::LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling, ::Integer, ::Integer) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/LinearAlgebra/src/uniformscaling.jl:329
  Array(::Any) where T<:AbstractArray at abstractarray.jl:22
Stacktrace:
 [1] CellularAutomata.CA2d(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,2}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64) at /home/jafar_isbarov/.julia/dev/CellularAutomata/src/2dim.jl:22
 [2] CellularAutomata.CA2d(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,2}, ::Int64) at /home/jafar_isbarov/.julia/dev/CellularAutomata/src/2dim.jl:21
 [3] turbine_test() at /home/jafar_isbarov/Documents/projects/CellularAutomata.jl/test/conway_test.jl:57
 [4] top-level scope at none:0
 [5] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [6] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [7] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [8] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:239
 [9] _start() at ./client.jl:432
in expression starting at /home/jafar_isbarov/Documents/projects/CellularAutomata.jl/test/runtests.jl:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make an un-initialized array of `eltype Int8`:

```
Array{Int8}(undef, h, w, gen)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I still get the same error.

Comment: https://github.com/ceferisbarov/CellularAutomata.jl/blob/9cf83920c2088b71dd5dc165756265c7adefe51a/src/2dim.jl#L22 you need to change this line right? have you restarted the session?

Comment: Yes, it is that line. I run `julia07 test/runtests.jl` directly from the terminal. Do I still need to restart something?

Comment: then it can't be the exact same error right? because you literally don't have the `Array(Int8, h, w, gen)` anymore

Comment: I edited the question to add the new error. I believe it is completely same.

Comment: Strange, if a MethodError happens there I'd expect some indication of the Int8 parameter in `Array{Int8}`, or the undef being listed as an argument. Maybe this undef call was written in 0.7 to call the old `Array(Int8, dims...)` method but I couldn't track down the source code (maybe undef and this method for Array are Core stuff?).

Comment: I am confused. Even after commenting out that line, I get the same error on the same line.

Comment: So, I have downloaded the repo as a package, and used the test files in another cloned directory to test this package, while changing the files in the latter, cloned directory. Nevermind that sentence, `Array{Int8}(undef, h, w, gen)` works. Thanks, and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: You might want to use Revise for development